# Ratio Correction

Tags: statistics, usage-statistics

In my study I calculate some ratios. The theoretical background is as follows:

There is the effect of Binocular Rivalry, where a different picture is presented to the left eye than to the right eye (e.g. a black and a white square). Most of the time, the test persons do not see a mixture of colours (i.e. something grey), but the picture changes back and forth, so a black square is seen once and then a white one. During the time of the trial (e.g. 60 seconds) the test persons indicate what they see (black square, white square, mixed picture). These durations can be used to calculate the predominance ratio as an indication of whether one stimulus is seen significantly more often than the other. The ratio is calculated from [T(stimulus1)-T(stimulus2)/T(stimulus1)+T(stimulus2)], where T is the cumulative time the stimulus was seen during the 60 seconds. The times for the mixed image are completely omitted from this calculation. In the end the ratio is tested if it is significantly different from zero with a one-sample t-test. If it is significantly different from zero and positive, stimulus 1 is seen longer, if it is significantly different from zero and negative, stimulus 2 is seen longer. Now I have two conditions and I calculate a predominance ratio for each.

Let us suppose that condition 1 would be the squares I mentioned above and condition 2 would be a stick figure in black and a tree in white. I want to know if there is a significant predominance ratio in the stickman/tree condition, but without the influence of the colors. Therefore I want to somehow deduct the predominance ratio from condition 1 from condition 2. So I would like to do a kind of "baseline correction". The value of this predominance ratio can vary between -1 and 1. Now my question is how to do this correction without changing the metrics of the ratio. In order to test the corrected ratio towards zero in a meaningful way, it must not take any other values than from -1 to 1.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Very interesting question, but since it is about concepts instead of a specific programming problem, it's suitable for stats.stackexchange.com instead of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Oh, good point. Thank you!